# how to manage some urls content from a file?

Tags: python, parsing, loops, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have defined a function like this:

```
def CiteParser():
    with open("/tmp/content.txt") as myfile:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile)
        result = []
        for cite in soup.find_all('cite'):
            result.append(cite.string.split('/')[0] + 'mystring')
        return u'\n'.join(result)
```

Now there is a problem:

I am calling this function from a loop.
In my `content.txt` I have many pages of my urls. But each time my loop is starting it just parses the first `usl` and it doesn't go to the next url from `content.txt`. How can I manage it?

## UPDATE

my content.txt is something like this:(but not one bing pages.Imagin there some pages in it)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:Web="http://schemas.live.com/Web/"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" /><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    si_ST=new Date
    //]]></script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    window.onerror||(window.onerror=function(n,t,i){var r="";r=typeof n=="object"&&n.srcElement&&n.srcElement.src?"\"ScriptSrc = '"+escape(n.srcElement.src.replace(/'/g,""))+"'\"":'"'+escape(n.replace(/"/g,""))+'","Meta":"'+escape(t)+'","Line":'+i,(new Image).src=_G.lsUrl+'&Type=Event.ClientInst&DATA=[{"T":"CI.Error","FID":"CI","Name":"JSError","Text":'+r+"}]",typeof sj_evt!="undefined"&&sj_evt.fire("ErrorInstrumentation",r)});_G={ST:(si_ST?si_ST:new Date),Mkt:"en-WW",RTL:false,Ver:"9_00_0_2878447",IG:"410c25a201f34abf9bb370be85752c1c",EventID:"da89958a1ec345d3a2b4d71cc2c99fbb",V:"web",P:"SERP",DA:"LON04v2",CID:"19621490B4626F483B0F12D4B5436FAF",SUIH:"3btJ3UTMuN9lsHY9kJ936w",PCId:"1",cUrl:"http:\/\/c.bing.com\/c.gif?DI=15074",akamaiSyncUrl:"http:\/\/cms.abmr.net\/pix?cid=1237&amp;uid=",gpUrl:"\/fd\/ls\/GLinkPing.aspx?"};_G.lsUrl="/fd/ls/l?IG="+_G.IG+"&CID="+_G.CID+"&PM=Y";curUrl="http:\/\/www.bing.com\/search";function si_T(a){if(document.images){_G.GPImg=new Image;_G.GPImg.src=_G.gpUrl+'IG='+_G.IG+'&CID='+_G.CID+'&PM=Y'+'&'+a;}return true;};
    //]]></script><style type="text/css">a{}</style><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    function si_sendCReq(){try{for(var t=0,n=_w;n!=n.parent&&t<10;){if(n.parent.location.hostname==_w.location.hostname)return;n=n.parent,t++}}catch(i){}_G.muidI=new Image,_G.muidI.onload=function(){var r=_d.cookie,t,n,i;return/\bTUID\b/i.test(r)?1:(_G.muidI2=new Image,_G.muidI2.src=_G.gpUrl+"CM=TMF&IG="+_G.IG+(_G.CID?"&CID="+_G.CID:""),t="MUID",n=sj_cook.get(t),n&&(i=n.substring(t.length+1),_G.muidI3=new Image,_G.muidI3.src=_G.akamaiSyncUrl.replace(/&amp;/g,"&")+i),1)},_G.muidI.src=_G.cUrl};
    //]]></script><title>ip:78.138.105.143 - Bing</title><link href="/search?format=rss&amp;q=ip%3a78.138.105.143&amp;qs=n&amp;pq=ip%3a78.138.105.143&amp;sc=0-0&amp;sp=-1&amp;sk=&amp;first=1&amp;FORM=PERE" rel="alternate" title="XML" type="text/xml"/><link href="/search?format=rss&amp;q=ip%3a78.138.105.143&amp;qs=n&amp;pq=ip%3a78.138.105.143&amp;sc=0-0&amp;sp=-1&amp;sk=&amp;first=1&amp;FORM=PERE" rel="alternate" title="RSS" type="application/rss+xml"/><link href="/s/a/bing_p.ico" rel="icon"/><style type="text/css">img,.cbtn,.sb_meta li,.exp_trwr .sc_rc1,.topBar .bg,.vidr cite.nowrap{vertical-align:bottom}img.img_fav,img.twss,img.twsi,img.sa_iconR{vertical-align:baseline}img.img_msn_icon,td.msn_btn_icon img{vertical-align:text-top}#sb_foot{margin-top:-3px}div.sb_adsWv2 h2.sb_title{display:block}html,body,h1,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,img,ol,ul,li,form,table,tr,th,td{border:0;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}input,textarea{font:inherit;font-size:100%}body{min-width:987px}body,.sb_text,.sb_h3{color:#000;font:small/normal Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif}a,.sb_link,a.sb_link,.sb_link a,.sb_h3 a{color:#04c;text-decoration:none}a:visited,a.sb_link:visited,.sb_link a:visited,.sb_h3 a:visited{color:#639}a:hover,a.sb_link:hover,.sb_link a:hover,h3 a,.sb_h3 a{text-decoration:underline}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:small;font-weight:200}h1{font-size:93%}h2,h3,.sb_h3{font-size:125%}h1,h1 a,h1 a:visited,h2,h2 a,h2 a:visited{color:#000}h2{margin:0 0 .62em}cite,.sb_cite{color:#388222;font-style:normal;word-wrap:break-word}strong{font-weight:700}.sb_title{font-size:91%;margin:0 0 .36em;text-transform:uppercase}.sb_count,.sb_meta,.sb_title,.sb_title a{color:#777}.sb_meta a,.sb_meta a:visited,a.sb_meta,a.sb_meta:visited{color:#36b}.sb_alert{color:#d90026}.sb_alert a{font-style:italic}#sw_hdr,#sw_content,#sw_main,#sw_foot{width:100%;float:left}#sw_content{position:static;z-index:3;min-height:344px}#sw_canvas{padding:0 0 0 15px;clear:both}#sw_main{_display:inline;margin:0 0 0 -15px;padding:0 0 1.54em 15px}.sb_results p,.sb_results .sb_meta{margin:0;line-height:1.2em;word-wrap:break-word}.sp_pss li{display:inline}.sb_pag{width:100%;float:left}.sb_pag li{float:left}.sb_pag h4{display:none}.sb_pag a,.sb_pag span{display:block;padding:.3em .7em;margin:0 .38em 0 0;text-align:center}a.sb_pagP,a.sb_pagN,span.sb_pagSp{padding:.38em .5em}.sb_pag a:hover,a.sb_pagS{text-decoration:none;background:#ededed}a.sb_pagS{color:#000}a.sb_pagP{margin-right:.7em;padding-left:0}a:hover.sb_pagP,a:hover.sb_pagN{text-decoration:underline;background-color:transparent}a.sb_pagP:visited,a.sb_pagN:visited{color:inherit}#sw_aside{width:185px;float:left;margin:0 0 0 -195px;overflow:hidden;word-wrap:break-word}.sw_menu{padding:0 20px}#sw_main .sw_menu{padding:0}.sw_menu form{margin:0;width:100%}.sw_menu ul{padding:0 0 1.52em;margin:0;list-style:none}.sw_menu ul ul{padding:0}.sw_menu li{padding:0 0 .3em}#sb_foot{font-size:83.9%;clear:both;float:left;width:550px;border-top:solid 1px #ccc;margin-left:110px;line-height:23px;_display:inline;_zoom:1}#sw_footL,#sw_footL a,#sw_foot3,#sw_foot3 a{color:#777;clear:both;margin:7px 0 43px 10px}#sw_foot3{margin-top:-43px}#sb_foot ul{display:block}#sb_foot li{display:inline}#sb_foot a,#sb_foot span{margin:.4em}a#sb_feedback{color:#04c}#sw_ctfm{margin:15px 0 0 10px;float:left}.sw_sb,.sw_qbtn,.sw_pifa,.sw_pipp,.sw_pippa,.sw_pil,.sw_pit,.sw_conv,.sw_conva,.sw_poi,.sw_poia{height:20px;width:20px}.sw_pref,.sw_play,.sw_playh,.sw_playa,.sw_playd,.sw_playp,.sw_spp,.sw_spr{height:16px;width:16px}.sw_sb,.sw_qbtn{background:-76px 0}.sw_ddbl,.sw_ddbk,.sw_ddw,.sw_ddgy,.sw_ddgn{background:-404px -22px;height:5px;width:8px;_font-size:0}.sw_ddbk{background:-412px -22px}.sw_ddw{background:-420px -22px}.sw_ddgy{background:-428px -22px}.sw_ddgn{background:-436px -22px}.sw_meIc{background:-108px 0;height:12px;width:10px}#spcv .sw_meIc{background-position:-97px 0}.sw_pref{background:-119px 0}.sw_calc{background:-389px 0;height:19px;width:19px}.sw_pifa{background:-137px 0}.sw_pifa.hover{background-position:-158px 0}.sw_pipp{background:-179px 0}.sw_pipp.hover{background-position:-200px 0}.sw_pippa{background:-221px 0}.sw_pil{background:-242px 0}.sw_pil.hover{background-position:-263px 0}.sw_pit{background:-284px 0}.sw_pit.hover{background-position:-305px 0}.sw_conv{background:-326px 0}.sw_conv:hover{background-position:-347px 0}.sw_conva{background:-368px 0}.sw_poi{background:-409px 0}.sw_poia{background:-430px 0}.sw_play{background:-451px 0}.sw_playh{background:-468px 0}.sw_playa{background:-485px 0}.sw_playd{background:-660px 0}.sw_playp{background:-677px 0}.sw_plus{background:-387px -20px;height:8px;width:8px}.sw_minus{background:-396px -21px;height:2px;width:8px}.sw_st,.sw_sth,.sw_ste,.sw_st2,.sw_sth2{background:-502px 0;height:12px;width:12px}.sw_st2{background:-530px 0}.sw_sth{background:-544px 0}.sw_sth2{background:-558px 0}.sw_ste{background:-516px 0}.sw_tpo,.sw_tpoh,.sw_tpoa{background:-502px -13px;height:12px;width:8px}.sw_tpoh{background:-511px -13px}.sw_tpoa{background:-520px -13px}.sw_tpcg,.sw_tpcbl,.sw_tpcw,.sw_tpcbk{background:-97px -17px;height:9px;width:9px}.sw_tpcbl{background:-107px -17px}.sw_tpcw{background:-117px -17px}.sw_tpcbk{background:-127px -17px}.sw_arw,.sw_arwh{background:-470px -17px;height:11px;width:14px}.sw_arwh{background:-485px -17px}.sw_beak{background:-451px -17px;height:11px;width:18px}.sw_tbcsp:hover{background-position:-126px -17px}.sw_spo,.sw_spc{background:-572px 0;height:28px;width:28px}.sw_spd{background:-601px 0;height:24px;width:24px}.sw_spp{background:-626px 0}.sw_spr{background:-643px 0}.sw_sb,.sw_qbtn,.sw_ddbl,.sw_ddbk,.sw_ddw,.sw_ddgy,.sw_ddgn,.sw_meIc,.sw_pref,.sw_logo,.sw_calc,.sw_pifa,.sw_pipp,.sw_pippa,.sw_pil,.sw_pit,.sw_conv,.sw_conva,.sw_poi,.sw_poia,.sw_play,.sw_playh,.sw_playa,.sw_playd,.sw_playp,.sw_st,.sw_sth,.sw_ste,.sw_st2,.sw_sth2,.sw_plus,.sw_minus,.sw_tpo,.sw_tpoh,.sw_tpoa,.sw_tpcg,.sw_tpcbl,.sw_tpcw,.sw_tpcbk,.sw_arw,.sw_arwh,.sw_beak,.sw_spo,.sw_spc,.sw_spd,.sw_spp,.sw_spr{background-image:url(/fd/s/a/sw17.png);background-repeat:no-repeat}.sw_logo{height:26px;width:75px;background-color:transparent}.idh{padding:0;margin:0;z-index:951}.idd{display:none;z-index:950;position:absolute;width:230px;right:5px}.img_uparrow{margin-left:16px;z-index:952;display:none}#id_t{white-space:nowrap;max-width:150px;overflow:visible}#id_la{cursor:pointer}.idh a:hover{text-decoration:none}.idh .lt{cursor:pointer;height:34px}.pic{vertical-align:middle;margin-left:10px}.pic.si{height:28px;width:28px}.idh .lt #id_t{display:block}.idh .lt #id_s,#id_n{padding-left:8px}.idh .lt #id_r{width:74px;height:13px;position:relative}.idh .lt #id_rc{line-height:13px;position:absolute;top:1px;left:21px}.idh .pref{position:absolute;right:15px;top:48px;cursor:pointer}.img_downarrow{margin-left:4px;vertical-align:middle;display:inline-block}div#sw_canvas{padding-left:120px}.sw_a{position:absolute;top:17px;left:122px;font-weight:700;font-size:84%;z-index:1001;text-transform:uppercase;white-space:nowrap}.sw_a li{display:inline;margin:0 1.8em 0 0;zoom:1}.sw_a a{color:#777;font-weight:700}.sw_aa a{color:#000}.sw_a2{margin:10px 0 20px 110px;padding:0;font-weight:700;font-size:85%;z-index:1001;text-transform:uppercase}.sw_a2 li{display:inline;padding:8px 10px;background:#f5f5f5}.sw_a2 a{color:#777}.sw_a2 .sw_aa{background:#e5e5e5}.sw_a3 .sw_aa{background:#fff}.sw_a3 li{background:#fff;text-transform:none;font-weight:200;font-size:115%}.sw_hdr_img,#sw_im{background:#d9d7cf no-repeat}#sw_page #sw_hdr{min-height:0;_height:auto}html{overflow-y:scroll}.sw_spc{-ms-transform:rotate(180deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);-moz-transform:rotate(180deg);-o-transform:rotate(180deg)}.nosp.idh{position:absolute;width:240px;height:78px;top:5px;display:none;background-color:#fff}.nosp.idd{top:85px}.nosp.idh .lt{margin-top:38px;margin-right:50px;_margin-right:24px;float:right}.nosp.idh span{color:#727272}.nosp.idh .lt .pic{border:1px solid #f2f2f2}.nosp .img_rwds_sml{position:absolute;top:1px;left:8px}#id_lt{height:34px}.nosp .img_uparrow{top:71px;position:absolute}.nosp.idh .pref:hover{background:url('/fd/s/a/identity6.png') no-repeat scroll -93px -1px transparent}#sw_tfbb{height:0}.sw_sb,.sw_qbtn,.sw_pifa,.sw_pipp,.sw_pippa,.sw_pil,.sw_pit,.sw_conv,.sw_conva,.sw_poi,.sw_poia{height:20px;width:20px}.sw_pref,.sw_play,.sw_playh,.sw_playa,.sw_playd,.sw_spp,.sw_spr{height:16px;width:16px}.sw_sb,.sw_qbtn{background:-76px 0}.sw_ddbl,.sw_ddbk,.sw_ddw,.sw_ddgy,.sw_ddgn{background:-404px -22px;height:5px;width:8px;_font-size:0}.sw_ddbk{background:-412px -22px}.sw_ddw{background:-420px -22px}.sw_ddgy{background:-428px -22px}.sw_ddgn{background:-436px -22px}.sw_meIc{background:-108px 0;height:12px;width:10px}#spcv .sw_meIc{background-position:-97px 0}.sw_pref{background:-119px 0}.sw_calc{background:-389px 0;height:19px;width:19px}.sw_pifa{background:-137px 0}.sw_pifa.hover{background-position:-158px 0}.sw_pipp{background:-179px 0}.sw_pipp.hover{background-position:-200px 0}.sw_pippa{background:-221px 0}.sw_pil{background:-242px 0}.sw_pil.hover{background-position:-263px 0}.sw_pit{background:-284px 0}.sw_pit.hover{background-position:-305px 0}.sw_conv{background:-326px 0}.sw_conv:hover{background-position:-347px 0}.sw_conva{background:-368px 0}.sw_poi{background:-409px 0}.sw_poia{background:-430px 0}.sw_play{background:-451px 0}.sw_playh{background:-468px 0}.sw_playa{background:-485px 0}.sw_playd{background:-660px 0}.sw_plus{background:-387px -20px;height:8px;width:8px}.sw_minus{background:-396px -21px;height:2px;width:8px}.sw_st,.sw_sth,.sw_ste,.sw_st2,.sw_sth2{background:-502px 0;height:12px;width:12px}.sw_st2{background:-530px 0}.sw_sth{background:-544px 0}.sw_sth2{background:-558px 0}.sw_ste{background:-516px 0}.sw_tpo,.sw_tpoh,.sw_tpoa{background:-502px -13px;height:12px;width:8px}.sw_tpoh{background:-511px -13px}.sw_tpoa{background:-520px -13px}.sw_tpcg,.sw_tpcbl,.sw_tpcw,.sw_tpcbk{background:-97px -17px;height:9px;width:9px}.sw_tpcbl{background:-107px -17px}.sw_tpcw{background:-117px -17px}.sw_tpcbk{background:-127px -17px}.sw_arw,.sw_arwh{background:-470px -17px;height:11px;width:14px}.sw_arwh{background:-485px -17px}.sw_beak{background:-451px -17px;height:11px;width:18px}.sw_tbcsp:hover{background-position:-126px -17px}.sw_spo,.sw_spc{background:-572px 0;height:28px;width:28px}.sw_spd{background:-601px 0;height:24px;width:24px}.sw_spp{background:-626px 0}.sw_spr{background:-643px 0}.sw_sb,.sw_qbtn,.sw_ddbl,.sw_ddbk,.sw_ddw,.sw_ddgy,.sw_ddgn,.sw_meIc,.sw_pref,.sw_logo,.sw_calc,.sw_pifa,.sw_pipp,.sw_pippa,.sw_pil,.sw_pit,.sw_conv,.sw_conva,.sw_poi,.sw_poia,.sw_play,.sw_playh,.sw_playa,.sw_playd,.sw_st,.sw_sth,.sw_ste,.sw_st2,.sw_sth2,.sw_plus,.sw_minus,.sw_tpo,.sw_tpoh,.sw_tpoa,.sw_tpcg,.sw_tpcbl,.sw_tpcw,.sw_tpcbk,.sw_arw,.sw_arwh,.sw_beak,.sw_spo,.sw_spc,.sw_spd,.sw_spp,.sw_spr{background-image:url(/sa/simg/sw_21_lg.png);background-repeat:no-repeat}.sw_logo{height:29px;width:73px;background-color:transparent;text-indent:-9999px}#sw_hdr .sw_box{padding:36px 0 0}#sw_hdr{min-height:100px;_height:100px;padding:0 0 4px 0;background:#fff}.sw_logo{_display:inline;margin:1px 10px 0 27px;float:left}.sw_logoT{color:#000;font-size:17px;line-height:normal;position:absolute;z-index:-1}#sw_hdr .sw_box{position:relative;z-index:901;float:left}.sw_hdr_img,#sw_im{height:5px;font-size:0;cursor:pointer}.sw_bd{position:relative;float:left;font-size:medium;border:1px #999 solid}.sw_b{float:none;padding:.19em .1em 1.06em .03em;height:13px}.sw_b input{float:left;border:0;-webkit-appearance:none;outline:none;font-family:"Segoe UI",Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif}.sw_qbox{margin:0 0 -.88em;padding:.19em .15em .25em .56em;height:22px;line-height:1.25em;width:480px}.sw_b .sw_sb,.sw_b .sw_qbtn{cursor:pointer;padding:0;margin:4px 6px -14px 8px;overflow:hidden;font-size:0}.sw_dvdr{background:#ccc;height:21px;margin:3px 0 -15px 12px;float:left;width:1px}#content .cttl{color:#404040!important}#content,#content a.sb_pagS,#sidebar DIV.sw_menu,#sidebar .ans,div.wpc_module h2,div.wpc_module .sb_h3,div.wpc_module .cbl,#content a.exp_trgr{color:#404040}#content .sb_adW a,#content .sb_adN a{color:#1020b0}#content .sb_adW a:visited,#content .sb_adN a:visited{color:#6010d0}#sidebar DIV.sw_menu a,div.wpc_module a,#content a,a#sb_feedback{color:#1020d0}#sidebar DIV.sw_menu a:visited,div.wpc_module a:visited,#content a:visited{color:#600090}#content cite,#content .sb_cite,#content .sb_meta CITE A{color:#009030}#content .sp_pss,#content .cllc p,#content .nc_os,#content .news_dt,#content .time,#content .sb_adW .sc_rtg,#sidebar .sb_add .sc_rtg,#sidebar .sb_meta,#sidebar .rrrs_ttl,#content a.exp_trgr{color:#606060}#content .sb_adW cite{color:#008030}#content .sb_adW p{color:#303030}#content .wpc_module h2,#content .wpc_module .sb_h3,#content .wpc_module .cbl{color:#000}#content{padding:8px 0 0;margin:0 0 0 -15px;display:inline-block}#results_area{float:left;width:550px}#sw_main{padding-bottom:0}#results_container{padding:0 15px 0 15px}#sidebar{float:left;padding:0 15px 0 26px;word-wrap:break-word}#results:after{clear:both;content:'.';display:block;height:0;visibility:hidden}.sb_ph{margin:20px 0 .93em;padding-bottom:10px;font-size:91%}.sb_ph .sb_count{float:left;text-transform:uppercase;color:#000;padding-right:25px}.sb_ph a{color:#737373;text-decoration:underline;*vertical-align:top}.sb_ph .ftrH{*vertical-align:baseline}#results_area .sb_pag{padding:1.33em 0 0;margin:0 0 40px 0}.sb_results li.sa_wr{padding:0 0 10px}.sa_mc{padding:0 0 10px}.sb_tlst,.sa_mc .sb_meta{word-wrap:break-word;padding:0 0 2px}div.wr_cm2 .sb_meta{padding:0}.sb_meta a,.sb_meta a:visited{color:#36b}.sp_pss{color:#777;line-height:1.2em}.sb_tlst H3,.sb_tlst div{display:inline}#results_removed{margin:0 0 24px}.sb_ans,.sa_wr{_margin-right:-3px;float:left;width:100%}#results{zoom:1}.sf,.sf_wa1{float:left}.sf_wa1{width:9.23em}.sf{width:100%}.sc_m4,.sc_m12{margin:0;clear:both}.sc_m4{margin:.2em .77em 0 0}.sc_m7{margin-top:.3em}.sc_m12{_height:2.4em;max-height:2.5em;*max-height:2.4em;margin-top:.3em}.sc_st div.sc_m4{overflow:hidden;height:1.35em}.sc_st div.sc_m12{overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis}.sc_f2{line-height:1.33em}.nowrap{white-space:nowrap;display:inline-block}.sn_att,.sn_pn{width:100%;float:left;margin-top:.77em}.sn_att2{width:100%;float:left;margin-top:2px}.sn_att,.sn_gr,sn_pn{clear:both;margin:0}.sn_att a:visited,.sn_att2 a:visited{color:#639}sn_cl{width:100%;float:left}.sn_rc,.sn_lc{width:250px;float:left;word-wrap:break-word}.sn_lc{padding-right:10px}.sn_mm{float:left;margin:0 .77em 0 0}.sn_rct{display:table;line-height:1.33em;zoom:1}.sn_gr{margin-top:.5em}.sc_m4:after,.ans2:after,.sn_gr:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;height:0;visibility:hidden}.ans2 .sc_hl1 li,.ans3 .sc_hl1 li,.ans2 ul.sc_gpl1 ul.sc_hl1,.ansC h3{display:inline}.ans3 .sc_rc1 img{vertical-align:-1px}.ans2 ul.sc_gpl1{margin-bottom:4px}.ans2 ul.sc_gpl1 h3{_clear:both;_display:inline;a:0}.ans3{max-width:585px;_zoom:1}.ans p,.ans ul{margin:0;padding:0}.ans ul{list-style-type:none}.ans .time,.ans h2{color:#525051}.ans h5{display:inline;margin:0 .5em 0 0}.ans h5{font-weight:400;font-size:100%}.ans2 h2 div span span{white-space:nowrap}#results .ans h2{float:none;width:auto;margin:0 0 .62em}.ans h3{font-weight:bold;color:#000}.ans h3 a{font-weight:normal}.ans h4.sc_ih1{float:left;margin:0 .5em 0 0;font-weight:400}.ans2 h2 div span span a{text-decoration:none}.ans2 h2 div span span a:hover,.ans h2 a{text-decoration:underline}.ans2 h2 span{color:#000}h2 div span a:visited,.ansC h2 a:visited{color:#639}h2 span{font-size:small;margin-left:.47em}.ansC{clear:left}.ans{margin-bottom:20px;*display:inline-block;a:0}.sb_results .sa_wr .ansC .ans{margin-bottom:0}.ans ul.sc_bl2 li:first-child{margin-bottom:.3em}.ansA .ans{background-image:none}.ansA .ans h3{color:#549c00;font-size:150%;font-weight:200}.sb_results .ansC .ans{_left:0}.ttl{display:none}.ansC ul,#results .ansC ul{margin:0}.ans h2 a{color:#04c}.c_tlbxTrg{height:14px;width:15px;display:inline-block;margin:-1px 6px -3px 2px;font-size:0}.c_tlbxH{display:none}.cchi{padding-top:3px}.crch{padding-top:5px}.cfct,.csec{color:#737373}.cttl{color:#000!important;margin:0!important;padding:0 0 2px}p.catr{clear:left;width:100%;padding:1px 0 2px 0}.catr cite{*float:left}.cchi{clear:left}.ansC{clear:left}.ans{margin-bottom:20px;*display:inline-block;a:0}.ans2:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;height:0;visibility:hidden}.ans h2 a{color:#04c;text-decoration:underline}.ans h2 a:visited{color:#639}.ans h2{color:#525051}</style><style type="text/css">.sw_hdr_img,#sw_im{background:#025285 no-repeat}</style><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    var amd,define,require;(function(n){function e(n,i,u){t[n]||(t[n]={dependencies:i,callback:u},r(n))}function r(){if(arguments.length==0){if(!f){for(var n in t)u(n);f=!0}return i}if(arguments.length==1)return u(arguments[0])}function u(n){var s,e;if(i[n])return i[n];if(t.hasOwnProperty(n)){var h=t[n],f=h.dependencies,l=h.callback,a=r,o={},c=[a,o];if(f.length<2)throw error("invalid usage");else if(f.length>2)for(s=f.slice(2,f.length),e=0;e<s.length;e++)c.push(u(s[e]));return l.apply(this,c),i[n]=o,o}}var t={},i={},f=!1;n.define=e,n.require=r})(amd||(amd={})),define=amd.define,require=amd.require;var _w=window,_d=document,sb_ie=window.ActiveXObject!==undefined,sb_i6=sb_ie&&!_w.XMLHttpRequest,_ge=function(n){return _d.getElementById(n)},sb_st=function(n,t){return setTimeout(n,t)},sb_ct=function(n){clearTimeout(n)},sb_gt=function(){return+new Date},sj_gx=function(){return sb_i6?new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP"):new XMLHttpRequest};_w.sj_ce=function(n){return _d.createElement(n)},_w.sk_merge||(_w.sk_merge=function(n){_d.cookie=n});define("fallback",["require","exports"],function(n,t){function f(){return function(){for(var t=[],i,n=0;n<arguments.length-0;n++)t[n]=arguments[n+0];i=e(arguments.callee),t[0]==="onPP"&&o(),i.push(t)}}function e(n){for(var t in i)if(i[t].h===n)return i[t].q}function u(n,t){for(var e=n.split("."),i=_w,u,r=0;r<e.length;r++)u=e[r],typeof i[u]=="undefined"&&t&&(i[u]=r===e.length-1?f():{}),i=i[u];return i}function o(){var e=i["rms.js"].q,o,f,t,n,r,u;if(e.length>0)for(o=!1,f=0;f<e.length;f++){for(t=e[f],n=0;n<t.length;n++)if(r=t[n]["A:Shared.Bundle"],r||(r=t[n]["A:rmsBu0"]),r){u=_d.createElement("script"),u.setAttribute("data-rms","1"),u.src=r,u.type="text/javascript",setTimeout(function(){_d.body.appendChild(u)},0),t.splice(n,1),o=!0;break}if(o)break}}function s(){for(var t,f,n=0;n<r.length;n++)t=r[n],f=u(t,!0),i[t]={h:f,q:[]}}function h(){for(var t,n=0;n<r.length;n++){var f=r[n],e=i[f].q,o=u(f);for(t=0;t<e.length;t++)o.apply(null,e[t])}}function c(n,t,i,r){(n===_w||n===_d||n===_d.body)&&t=="load"?_w.sj_evt.bind("onP1",i,!0):n.addEventListener?n.addEventListener(t,i,r):n.attachEvent?n.attachEvent("on"+t,i):n["on"+t]=i}var r=["rms.js","sj_evt.bind","sj_evt.fire","sj_jb","sj_wf","sj_cook.get","sj_cook.set","sj_pd","sj_sp","sj_be","sj_go","sj_ue","sj_evt.unbind","sj_et","Log.Log"],i={};t.replay=h,s(),_w.sj_be=c});function lb(){_w.si_sendCReq&&sb_st(_w.si_sendCReq,800),_w.lbc&&_w.lbc()};var si_PP=function(n,t){var i,u,f,e,o,h,c,r,l,s;if(!_G.PPS){for(u=["FC","BC","H","BP",null];i=u.shift();)u.push('"'+i+'":'+(_G[i+"T"]?_G[i+"T"]-_G.ST:-1));if(f=_w.performance&&_w.performance.timing,e=null,f&&(o=["unloadEventStart","unloadEventEnd","redirectStart","redirectEnd","fetchStart","domainLookupStart","domainLookupEnd","connectStart","connectEnd","secureConnectionStart","requestStart","responseStart","domLoading","domInteractive","domContentLoadedEventStart","domContentLoadedEventEnd","domComplete","loadEventStart","loadEventEnd","msFirstPaint","responseEnd",""],h=f.navigationStart,h>=0)){for(l=s=c=0;i=o.shift();c++)r=f[i],r>0&&(l|=1<<c,r-=h,o.push(r===s?"":(r-s).toString(16)),s=r);e=',"w3c":"'+l.toString(16)+","+o.join()+'"'}_G.PPImg=new Image,_G.PPImg.src=_G.lsUrl+'&Type=Event.CPT&DATA={"pp":{"S":"'+(t||"L")+'",'+u.join(",")+',"CT":'+(n-_G.ST)+',"IL":'+_d.images.length+"}"+(_G.C1?","+_G.C1:"")+(e!==null?e:"")+"}"+(_G.P?"&P="+_G.P:"")+(_G.DA?"&DA="+_G.DA:"")+(_G.MN?"&MN="+_G.MN:""),_G.PPS=1,sb_st(function(){sj_evt.fire("onPP")},1)}};_w.onbeforeunload=function(){si_PP(new Date,"A")};function si_ct(n,t){var i="getAttribute",r,u,f;try{for(;n!==document.body;n=n.parentNode){if(r=n.tagName=="A"&&n[i]("h")||n[i]("_ct"),r){u=n[i]("_ctf")||"si_T",_w[u]&&_w[u]("&"+r);break}if(t)break}}catch(e){}return!0}(function(){sj_be(document,"mousedown",function(n){si_ct(sb_ie?event.srcElement:n.target)},!1)})();var wlc_d = 1500,wlc_t = 63536526142;;(function(n){var i,r,t;if(document.querySelector){i=[],r="ad";function u(){var c=sb_gt(),u=document.documentElement,r=document.body,f=-1,e=-1,o=u.clientHeight,s=["#b_results .b_ad",".sb_adsWv2",".ads"],t,h,n;if(r){for(t=0;t<s.length;t++)if(h=s[t],n=document.querySelector(h),n&&n.offsetTop<o){f=n.offsetHeight,e=n.offsetTop;break}i=[e,f,u.clientWidth,o,r.offsetWidth,r.offsetHeight,sb_gt()-c]}}n?(t=n.onbeforefire,n.onbeforefire=function(){t&&t(),u(),n.mark(r,i)}):(t=si_PP,si_PP=function(){u();var n='"'+r+'":['+i.join()+"]";_G.C1=_G.C1?_G.C1+","+n:n,t.apply(null,[].slice.apply(arguments))})}})(_w.pp);var sj_log=function(n,t,i){var r=new RegExp('"',"g");(new Image).src=_G.lsUrl+'&Type=Event.ClientInst&DATA=[{"T":"'+n+'","FID":"CI","Name":"'+t+'","Text":"'+escape(i.replace(r,""))+'"}]'};_w.AM=["live.com","virtualearth.net","windows.net","onenote.com","hexun.com","dict.bing.com.cn","msn.com","variflight.com","bing.net"];(function(){function f(t,r){var u=t.tagName;return(u==="SCRIPT"&&(n.href=t.src)||u==="OBJECT"&&t.type&&t.type.indexOf("flash")>0&&(n.href=t.data))&&n.href.length>0&&n.hostname.length>0&&n.hostname!==location.hostname&&!e(n.hostname)?(sj_log("CI.AntiMalware",r,u.substr(0,1)+":"+n.href.substr(0,i)),!1):!0}function e(n){for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++)if(n.indexOf(t[i])>=0)return!0;return!1}var t=_w.AM,i=100,n=document.createElement("A"),r,u;document.write=function(n){n.length>0&&sj_log("CI.AntiMalware","DW",n.substr(0,i))},typeof Element!="undefined"&&Element.prototype&&(r=Element.prototype.appendChild,Element.prototype.appendChild=function(n){return f(n,"AC")?r.apply(this,arguments):null},u=Element.prototype.insertBefore,Element.prototype.insertBefore=function(n){return f(n,"IB")?u.apply(this,arguments):null})})();
    //]]></script><!-- FD: 3199A45BC1782ABCC0516DD723814485 --></head><body class=" en en-ww" onload="if(_w.lb)lb();"><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    _G.PCT=new Date
    //]]></script><!--FdBodyAsync--><div id="sw_page"><div id="sw_width"><div class="sw_hdr_bg" id="sw_hdr"><div class="idh nosp" id="id_h"><table class="lt" id="id_l" _ct="ID=PJ,1.1"><tr id="id_lt"><td><img id="id_p" class="pic si" style="display:none" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBTAA7" title=""/></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="id_la"><div id="id_t"><span id="id_n" style="display:none"></span><span id="id_s">Sign in</span><span id="id_a" class="img_downarrow sw_ddb sw_ddgy">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></div></a></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><div class="img_uparrow sw_beak" id="id_d_u"></div></td></tr></table><a href="/account/general?ru=http%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsearch%3fq%3dip%3a78.138.105.143%26qs%3dn%26pq%3dip%3a78.138.105.143%26sc%3d0-0%26sp%3d-1%26sk%3d%26first%3d1%26FORM%3dPERE&amp;FORM=SEFD" class="pref sw_pref" title="Preferences" _ct="ID=PJ,2.1"></a></div><div id="sw_tfbb"></div><span class="idd nosp" id="id_d" _iid="PJ.5"></span><a href="/?FORM=HDRHME" title="Explore today’s homepage" h="ID=SERP,5030.1"><div class="sw_hdr_img"><div id="sw_im"></div></div></a><form action="/search" id="sb_form" class="sw_box" ><a href="/?FORM=Z9FD1" class="sw_logo" h="ID=SERP,5028.1"><span class="sw_logoT">Bing</span></a><div class="sw_bd"><div class="sw_b" id="sw_b"><input class="sw_qbox" id="sb_form_q" name="q" title="Enter your search term" type="text" value="ip:78.138.105.143" onfocus="document.getElementById('sw_b').style.borderColor='#3366bb';" onblur="document.getElementById('sw_b').style.borderColor = '#999';" maxlength="1000"/><div class="sw_dvdr"></div><input id="sb_form_go" class="sw_qbtn" title="Search" tabIndex="0" name="go" type="submit" value=""/></div><input id="sa_qs" name="qs" value="ds" type="hidden"/></div><input type="hidden" value="QBRE" name="form"/></form></div><div id="sw_content"><div></div><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    _G.AppVer="8_01_1_2887305";
    //]]></script><!--snr2--><!--wm--><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    _G.FCT=new Date
    //]]></script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    _G.BCT=new Date
    //]]></script><style type="text/css">div#sw_canvas{padding-left:120px}#sw_hdr{min-height:0;_height:auto}</style><style type="text/css">#sidebar{width:245px}.sw_a{position:absolute;top:17px;left:122px;font-weight:700;font-size:84%;z-index:1001;text-transform:uppercase;white-space:nowrap}.sw_a li{display:inline;margin:0 1.8em 0 0;zoom:1}.sw_a a{color:#777;font-weight:700}.sw_aa a{color:#000}.sw_a2{margin:10px 0 20px 110px;padding:0;font-weight:700;font-size:85%;z-index:1001;text-transform:uppercase}.sw_a2 li{display:inline;padding:8px 10px;background:#f5f5f5}.sw_a2 a{color:#777}.sw_a2 .sw_aa{background:#e5e5e5}.sw_a3 .sw_aa{background:#fff}.sw_a3 li{background:#fff;text-transform:none;font-weight:200;font-size:115%}</style><div><div id="sw_canvas"><div id="sw_main"><ul class="sw_a"><li class="sw_aa"><a href="/?scope=web&amp;FORM=HDRSC1" h="ID=SERP,5229.1">Web</a></li><li><a href="/images/search?q=ip%3a78.138.105.143&amp;FORM=HDRSC2" h="ID=SERP,5223.1">Images</a></li><li><a href="/videos/search?q=ip%3a78.138.105.143&amp;FORM=HDRSC3" h="ID=SERP,5224.1">Videos</a></li><li><a href="/news/search?q=ip%3a78.138.105.143&amp;FORM=HDRSC4" h="ID=SERP,5225.1">News</a></li><li><a href="/explore?q=ip%3a78.138.105.143&amp;FORM=HDRSC5" h="ID=SERP,5226.1">More</a></li></ul><div class="sb_ph" id="tw"><span class="sb_count" id="count">10,400 results</span></div><div id="content"><div id="results_area"><div id="results_container"><!-- snr --><div id="results"><ul id="wg0" class="sb_results"><li class="sa_wr"><div class="sa_cc" u="0|5045|4735365968236910|_mzMXEsCeh1pZWgn3ltY1CvygytGJtzt"><div Class="sa_mc"><div class="sb_tlst"><h3><a href="http://taksuncontrol.com/" h="ID=SERP,5069.1">تکسان کنترل</a></h3></div><div class="sb_meta"><cite>taksuncontrol.com</cite><span class="c_tlbxTrg"><span class="c_tlbxH" H="BASE:CACHEDPAGEDEFAULT" K="SERP,5071.1"></span></span></div><p>به وبسایت شرکت تکسان کنترل خوش آمدید! شركت تکسان کنترل فعالیت خود را به عنوان تولید كننده ...</p></div></div></li><li class="sa_wr"><div class="sa_cc" u="1|5046|4743251550085295|CbNAtAlUe9hs-0s5bPT-5-O4OjuxLD9X"><div Class="sa_mc"><div class="sb_tlst"><h3><a href="http://www.royal-jelve.ir/" h="ID=SERP,5082.1">شرکت رویال جلوه جنوب</a></h3></div><div class="sb_meta"><cite>www.royal-jelve.ir</cite>
```

YOU CAN READ FURTHURE [HERE](https://github.com/MortezaLSC/Puplic/blob/master/file.xml)

Thank you

Comment: What is inside `content.txt`?

Comment: some url contents from site `bing`. each page hase 10 result of bing search..but in each loop it returns me only the first page of bing search that has 10 site result

Comment: ok, thanks, what does it print: `print len(soup.find_all('cite'))`?

Comment: For the provided `content.txt` I got two strings separated by a new line: `taksuncontrol.commystring` and `www.royal-jelve.irmystring`. Is this what you are getting to?

Comment: Yes..this belonges to one bing page(that contains 10 results ot site.but I didn't put it completely) it has some of these contents from in content.txt...you can do one thing:plese in bing search wrire:`IP:78.138.105.143` so you have some pages as result...in this case it returns me just page #1 from bing search...

Comment: But I have for example 5 pages of bing that are 50 urls...but it returns me page #1 5 times

Comment: @MortezaLSC Please, do mind providing imports needed by your code. Otherwise you ask for guess work and this might lead to confusion. Just one line and it often turns your code to running example which is easy to answer.

Comment: Just FYI, there is a `bing search API` out there, and [python bindings](https://code.google.com/p/pybing/). Could be at least less painful to get the results.

Comment: Does replacing `soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile)` with `soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile, "html.parser")` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile, "lxml")` change anything?

Comment: Pardon for delayin: imagin my content.txt is sth like [this](https://github.com/MortezaLSC/Puplic/blob/master/file.xml)

Comment: @alecxe Thankyou..I would test it

Comment: @ alecxe Yes . with `html.parser` it is working...but I think there is a problem in my loop...Thank you...your answer would be accepted if you put it in answer part..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [underlying parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) by replacing:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile)
```

with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile, "html.parser")
```

Or, instead of `html.parser` you can also use `lxml` (first need to install it). Should be much faster.

Also see: [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).